# Вылетает исключение при попытке получить внешний IP

Tags: c#, ip, сеть

Пытаюсь получить внешний `IP` адрес с помощью библиотеки `NATUPNPLib`, но вылетает исключение `COMException`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NATUPNPLib;
using System.Net;

namespace ExternalIP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private UPnPNAT objRouter;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GetExternalIPFromRouter());
        }

        public string GetExternalIPFromRouter()
        {
            objRouter = new UPnPNAT();
            IStaticPortMappingCollection objPortMapCollection = objRouter.StaticPortMappingCollection;
            if ((objPortMapCollection == null) == false)
            {
                    string strExternalIP = null;
                    foreach (IStaticPortMapping temp in objPortMapCollection)//здесь вылетает исключение
                    {
                        strExternalIP = temp.ExternalIPAddress.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    return strExternalIP;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Sorry! Unable to Get External/WAN IP!";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Два вопроса:

1. Почему вылетает исключение?
2. В каких то случаях исключение не вылетает, но вместо IP возвращается строка "Sorry! Unable to Get External/WAN IP!". Лечится это отключением-включением сетевого адаптера. Почему StaticPortMappingCollection пуст и как это исправить?

Текст исключения:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException не обработано
HResult=-2147220984
Message=Компонент, предоставляемый пользователем, или произошло исключение для клиента (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80040208)
Source=mscorlib
ErrorCode=-2147220984
StackTrace:
    в System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
    в System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
    в System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()
    в ExternalIP.Form1.GetExternalIPFromRouter() в c:\Users\Artem\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ExternalIP\ExternalIP\Form1.cs:строка 35
    в ExternalIP.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в c:\Users\Artem\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ExternalIP\ExternalIP\Form1.cs:строка 25
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
    в System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
    в ExternalIP.Program.Main() в c:\Users\Artem\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ExternalIP\ExternalIP\Program.cs:строка 19
    в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
    в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
    в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
    в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: Приложите к вопросу текст исключения

Comment: @gil9red приложил